# How to configure AWS Elastic Beanstalk for a Node.js WebSocket server?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment, websocket, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm writing a pure Node.js WebSocket server with:

- AWS Elastic Beanstalk
- AWS Relational Database Service (RDS) for PostgreSQL
- AWS Simple Notification Service (SNS) for Apple Push Notification Service (APNs)
- [Node.js ws module](https://github.com/einaros/ws)
- [Node.js pg module](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres)

I also want it to be secure, e.g.:

- WSS (WebSockets over SSL/TLS)
- DoS attack prevention

I've changed "proxy server" to "none," but which other configurations should I change?